# BackgroundService class running in Docker linux container does not shutdown gracefully

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core-3.0

I've created a worker service that inherits from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService which I then deploy to a docker linux container on my windows machine through visual studio debugger. I put a breakpoint on code that happens when the cancellationtoken.IsCancellationRequested is true.
I then issue a "docker stop --time=30" to the container, the breakpoint is never hit and after 30 seconds the debugger stops forcefully.

I also tried overriding the StopAsync method and put a breakpoint in there and that also does not get called. 
I am running .net core 3, latest version of docker desktop.
I have confirmed that StartAsync gets called.

This is my program file.

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>();    });

    }
```

If anyone has an idea of what I missed, or a working example for a non webserver service that respects the stop i'd be very grateful.

Adding what my worker looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyWorker
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {    
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configs)
        {

        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);   
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        { 
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }


        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                await DoWork(cancellationToken); //While loop that checks token in here
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the *Worker*-code?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Docker or Linux. You never tell `Worker` to stop. If you use the .NET Core 3 Worker template, it won't stop until the process terminates, eg in response to a Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z in the console, a KILL signal in Linux etc. That's the job of a service/worker/daemon after all

Comment: When *do* you want it to stop? There are many ways to do this - you can get an instance of the service from DI and call `StopAsync` explicitly or you can get the [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and call `StopApplication` directly. That's what the `Ctrl+C` handler does too. This will signal all background services to stop

Comment: Are you following [Gunnar Peipman's article](https://gunnarpeipman.com/dotnet-core-worker-service/) perhaps? The worker in the second example won't stop until you hit Ctrl+C

Comment: I also explicitly used UseConsoleLifetime, even though it should be the default, right?
 Now this says 
"Listens for Ctrl+C or SIGTERM and calls StopApplication() to start the shutdown process. This will unblock extensions like RunAsync and WaitForShutdownAsync." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.useconsolelifetime?view=aspnetcore-3.0)  And the docker stop command should be issuing the SIGTERM to my application.  (https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want it to stop when i issue a docker stop command

Comment: @vladimir adding it to the question

Comment: Could you replace *await DoWork(cancellationToken);* with *await Task.Delay(1*60*60*1000, cancellationToken)* and test it again?

Comment: just tried it, same thing, doesnt stop at the StopAsync

Comment: Another weird thing, even if i try to attach to the   System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading event i dont see my breakpoint getting hit.

Comment: @Amir have you *tested* the code? A Backgroundservice *will* stop when it receives SIGTERM or SIGKILL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well after 4 days I finally figured it out, the problem is not with the code or the docker, the problem is with the Visual Studio debugger. If you are running your code by pressing play in VS2019 it will not respect the SIGTERM. If you run through the manual docker run command you will see your code respond to a DOCKER STOP command.

There might be a way to get it to work eventually but I haven't found it.

Comment: Hello man, do you found any answers for your problem? I'm struggling with this too.

Answer (score 10):

To listen to Ctrl+C, SIGINT and SIGTERM you need to add [Console Lifetime support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#runconsoleasync), either through [UseConsoleLifetime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.useconsolelifetime?view=aspnetcore-3.0) or [RunConsoleAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.runconsoleasync?view=aspnetcore-3.0),eg :

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

or

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).UseConsoleLifetime().Build().Run();
}
```

If shutting down takes longer than the timeout set in [ShutdownTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#shutdowntimeout), a warning is logged.

**How it works**

Knowing how the Console lifetime works can help troubleshoot delays.

If you check the source,[RunConsoleAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L170) is nothing more than a call to `UseConsoleLifetime().Build().RunAsync();`

The internal [ConsoleLifetime](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/ConsoleLifetime.cs) class [adds event listeners](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/ConsoleLifetime.cs#L60) for the `Cancel` and `ProcessExit` events :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += OnProcessExit;
Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancelKeyPress;
```

Ctrl+C [will only forwart the Stop request to the host](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/ConsoleLifetime.cs#L92) :

```
private void OnCancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
}
```

The `ProcessExit` handler on the other hand will emit a warning if shutting down takes longer than the timeout specified in [HostOptions.ShutdownTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#shutdowntimeout) :

```
private void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
    if(!_shutdownBlock.WaitOne(HostOptions.ShutdownTimeout))
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Waiting for the host to be disposed. Ensure all 'IHost' instances are wrapped in 'using' blocks.");
    }
    _shutdownBlock.WaitOne();
    // On Linux if the shutdown is triggered by SIGTERM then that's signaled with the 143 exit code.
    // Suppress that since we shut down gracefully. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6526
    System.Environment.ExitCode = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encrease shutdown timeout work for me. Thank you Panagiotis for share MS Docs.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.Configure<HostOptions>(option =>
    {
        option.ShutdownTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    });
});
```